# Replace values in a dataframe from another df

Tags: python, pandas

DF1:

```
ID  PRICE  WEIGHT STOCK 
1     20     100    30
2     30     200    10
3     40     300    20
```

DF2:

```
ID   WEIGHT   STOCK
2      90       40
3      400      70
```

I want to replace the values in df1 with the correct ones from df2

I'm trying to get this result:

```
ID  PRICE  WEIGHT STOCK 
1     20     100   30
2     30     90    40
3     40     400   70
```

Comment: Did you consider an outer join plus an np.where to pick the second case if it's not null?

Comment: `pd.concat([df2,df1]).groupby(['ID']).first()` or look at `df1.update(df2)`, but you'd need `ID` as index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
out = df1.set_index('ID')
out.update(df2.set_index('ID'))
out = out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   ID  PRICE  WEIGHT  STOCK
0   1     20   100.0   30.0
1   2     30    90.0   40.0
2   3     40   400.0   70.0
```

Comment: after update it returns a nonetype df

Comment: I do not know why: I have just tried again here and it appears to be working fine.

Comment: I guess you have assigned `out.update(df2.set_index('ID'))` to a dataframe, but you should not, since update is done in place!

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3],
                   'PRICE': [20, 30, 40],
                   'WEIGHT': [100, 200, 300],
                   'STOCK': [30, 10, 20],
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [2, 3],
                   'WEIGHT': [90, 400],
                   'STOCK': [40, 70],
                   })

df2 = df2.set_index('ID')
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df1.loc[df2.index,['WEIGHT', 'STOCK']] = df2[['WEIGHT', 'STOCK']]

print(df1.reset_index())
```

```py
   ID  PRICE  WEIGHT  STOCK
0   1     20     100     30
1   2     30      90     40
2   3     40     400     70
```